# ftp_fget(): Server cannot accept argument for random read

Tags: php, iis, ftp

I am connecting to FTP using ftp_connect and ftp_login.

```
    $this->connID = ftp_connect($this->host, 21, static::FTP_TIMEOUT);
    if (!$this->connID) {
        throw new \Exception('Connection to FTP: '. $this->host .' failed.');
    }       

    $loginResult = ftp_login($this->connID, $this->username, $this->password);
    if(!$loginResult) {
        throw new \Exception('Auth for FTP user ' .$this->username. ' failed.');
    }
```

After that I perform checks whether DIR exists using below command set.

```
    $resultPwd = ftp_pwd($this->connID);
    if ($resultPwd===false) {
        throw new \Exception ('Command ftp_pwd failed.');
    }

    $resultChdir = ftp_chdir($this->connID, $this->filesDir);
    if ($resultChdir===false) {
        throw new \Exception ('ftp_chdir failed, its most likely that directory: ' .$this->filesDir . ' does not exists');
    }

    $resultChdirBack = ftp_chdir($this->connID, $resultPwd);
    if ($resultChdirBack===false) {
        throw new \Exception ('Directory test failed, coult not set back directory to: '. $resultChdirBack);
    }
```

After that I am getting list of files (about 200) with below code:

```
$arrFilePath= ftp_nlist($this->connID, $this->filesDir);
```

After that I iterate over files and read them:

```
$resultGet = ftp_fget($this->connID, $fhTemp, $remoteFilePath, FTP_ASCII);
```

The problem is that for after reading unknown number of files ftp_fget fails and I get the:

```
Warning: ftp_fget(): Server cannot accept argument.
```

I've tried also each file iteration to close connection and open it again, however it did not solve the problem.

I was also trying to set up the passive connection, but my FTP servers seems to not work with passive mode correctly, because each single command fails after switching to passive mode.

Also I've increasted timeout to 15 seconds.

What could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach the full code through pastebin or something. I can connect to my ftp server and try to regenerate the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the [PHP FTP extension source code over at github](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/ftp). I did not find that string. This makes me believe that the message is not from PHP itself, but from the FTP server.

I recommend you either enable logging at the FTP server part to check the problem, or have a look at the actual network traffic using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) while your script runs.

You should add an excerpt of the dump to the question. And if you figured out the problem and solved it, feel free to answer your own question.